# Want to display texts based on what radio is selected with CSS applied

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am stuck on this past 2-3 days as I am new to this. I am making a HTML form and styling it with CSS. The texts that appear are in listed order and one of the lists has 2 radio buttons. Selecting either of them should take you to a different page showing/asking the questions that is based on the selection.

I am having problem figuring this out. How can display that text based on the selection. Here is the part of my code. I am using conditionals to know what is being selected.

```js
function check() {
  if(document.getElementById("radio_myself").checked) {
      document.write("<li><label class='fs-field-label fs-anim-upper' for='q1'>What's your name?</label></li>");
  }
  else {
      // show text;
  }
}
```

```html
<li data-input-trigger>
<label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q1">Welcome <br> <br> Is this application for yourself or someone else?</label>
<span><input onchange="check(); return false;" id="radio_myself" name="radMyself" type="radio" value="Myself"/>Myself</span>
<span><input onchange="check(); return false;" id="radio_selse" name="radSelse" type="radio" value="Someone"/>Someone Else</span>
```

I want it to display according to how I styled by CSS. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this  ?

```
<li data-input-trigger>
  <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q1">Welcome <br> <br> Is this application for yourself or someone else?</label>
  <span><input onchange="check(); return false;" id="radio_myself" name="radMyself" type="radio" value="Myself"/>Myself</span>
  <span><input onchange="check(); return false;" id="radio_selse" name="radMyself" type="radio" value="Someone"/>Someone Else</span>
  <script>
    function check() {
      if (document.getElementById("radio_myself").checked) {
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "What's your name?";

      } else if (document.getElementById("radio_selse").checked) {
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "What's your friends name?";
      }
    }

  </script>
  <p>
    <label id="test"></label>
  </p>
```

Comment: It somewhat does work. Can you please explain what label id "test" does?

Comment: it uses the label as a placeholder to display the message for check() function.

Comment: If you make document.write it replaces the page but if you declare an ID in a container you can add text and what you want

Comment: Exact AmirHossein Rd  i'm French my English is not easy Page is the Frame.

Comment: You could change by class selector 
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("example"); <label  class="example"  ></label> but an id shoud be single